# Standard input image data set for jpeg decoder

Tags: png, jpeg, codec

Can any one suggest me from where I can freely download the standard input dataset for the MJPEG codec (encoder and decoder).

I need this mentioned inputs for testing my codec.

For example: Lena, Airplane, and Baboon etc

[Standard_Input_Dataset_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKRkb.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will help you,

There are available sequence.

https://media.xiph.org/video/derf/